# How to change text label when scroll view goes to view 2?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm making a select level with 3 levels that get scrolled horizontally - the scroll controls three views "View 1" "view 2" and "View 3", I need to make an illusion to the user, Ive placed 3 buttons on each view and half a button on each side of the UIview with 2 labels one writes "lev" the other "el 2"...

When the user moves to View 2 I'd like the label to be set to "el 2" and as soon as the scroll has settled on level 2 i'd like the label to write "el 1" - This would make an illusion and it would be so fast that the user wouldn't notice.

heres the code: 
This:

```
[_elone setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Level 2"]];
```

But I don't know where to put it,
Should I make an outlet, an action a statement?

```
@interface PagerViewController ()
@property (assign) BOOL pageControlUsed;
@property (assign) NSUInteger page;
@property (assign) BOOL rotating;
- (void)loadScrollViewWithPage:(int)page;
@end

@implementation PagerViewController

@synthesize scrollViewTwo;
@synthesize pageControlTwo;
@synthesize pageControlUsed = _pageControlUsed;
@synthesize page = _page;
@synthesize rotating = _rotating;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
[self.scrollViewTwo setPagingEnabled:YES];
[self.scrollViewTwo setScrollEnabled:YES];
[self.scrollViewTwo setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
[self.scrollViewTwo setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
[self.scrollViewTwo setDelegate:self];

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

for (NSUInteger i =0; i < [self.childViewControllers count]; i++) {
    [self loadScrollViewWithPage:i];
}

self.pageControlTwo.currentPage = 0;
_page = 0;
[self.pageControlTwo setNumberOfPages:[self.childViewControllers count]];

UIViewController *viewController = [self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:self.pageControlTwo.currentPage];
if (viewController.view.superview != nil) {
    [viewController viewWillAppear:animated];
}

self.scrollViewTwo.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollViewTwo.frame.size.width * [self.childViewControllers count], scrollViewTwo.frame.size.height);
}

- (void)loadScrollViewWithPage:(int)page {
if (page < 0)
    return;
if (page >= [self.childViewControllers count])
    return;

// replace the placeholder if necessary
UIViewController *controller = [self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:page];
if (controller == nil) {
    return;
}

// add the controller's view to the scroll view
if (controller.view.superview == nil) {
    CGRect frame = self.scrollViewTwo.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    controller.view.frame = frame;
    [self.scrollViewTwo addSubview:controller.view];
}

}
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
_pageControlUsed = NO;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
_pageControlUsed = NO;
 }

- (IBAction) changePage :(id) sender {

}
```

How is this done?

Comment: Wait, I think all I have to do is extend the labels, oops, Wait No! Help? pls

Comment: Make this VC the scroll view's delegate, and implement scrollViewDidScroll.  In there, you can check scrollView.contentOffset and compare it to the view origins.

Comment: Here a helpful tutorial (check the paging example at the bottom too): http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// Implement the UIScrollview Delegate method

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender

{

CGFloat pageWidth = yourScrollView.frame.size.width;
int currentPage = floor((yourScrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;

 if (currentPage != featureVenPageControll.currentPage) 
{
    [_elone setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Level 2"]];
}

 }
```

Comment: Hey, I've used this I can seem to make it work, The _btnIllusionLeft only gets set hidden when its on View2 and I need it to be set Hidden on view 1 and only appear on view 2 and 3, and the _btnIllusionRight is not hiding when the page gets to View3. infact I need it hidden on view 3 before the scroll even gets there... 

Another thing, Its not appearing back to normal once it leaves from View 2...